# Firebase Database querying with search bar

Tags: json, swift, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

[image of data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUTM4.png)Trying to search for names in my database with a search bar. Trying to print the data but nothing is printing and I'm also not getting any errors. I was initially getting an error with the database rules, but I fixed that and still nothing. The "`DATA DOES NOT EXIST`" is not printing either.

Here is my code:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: 
String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        search = searchBar.text
        searchDatabase(name: search)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchDatabase(name: String!) {

    let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    dbRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "fullname").queryEqual(toValue: name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if !snapshot.exists() {
            // Name doesnt exist
            print("DATA DOES NOT EXIST")
        }

        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: String]] {
            //it should exist if it reaches here

            print(data)
        }
    })
}
```

And here are database rules:

```
{
"rules": {
"users": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".indexOn" : ["fullname"]
},
   "posts": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != null"
}
}
}
```

Database structure is something like this:
      
      `"users": { 
        "uid": { 
         "fullname": "firstname lastname", 
         "username": "12345user"

           } 
         }`

Comment: Nobody even knows what your data tree looks like.

Comment: "users": {
     "uid": {
      "fullname": "firstname lastname",
      "username": "12345user"
      }
    }

Comment: Added an image of the data tree.